# Terminating Armadillo program when condition is met

Tags: rcpp, armadillo

I was wondering how I can terminate some Armadillo program if a certain condition is met.

I use RcppArmadillo to run a program. However, the program may get numerically unstable at times and produce NaN output. What I would like to do is to terminate the program if some variable takes on NaN. The Armadillo documentation did not list anything about "termination", "stopping", or "aborting" a program.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That question is not specific to Rcpp, Armadillo, or RcppArmadillo.

You could just `throw()` an exception and then `catch()` -- but the real solution probably is to try to fix the underlying issue causing the instability.